# Why wont my fetch finish when i'm including parameters

Tags: reactjs, api, asp.net-core

I have been trying to fetch some data from one of my components in React, but when i include a parameter in the url, nothing happens and the fetch method never finishes.

This is my fetch method

```
fetch(`api/SampleData/GetTemplate/${this.props.match.params.orderId}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ Template: data, loading: false  });

            });
```

And this is my api get method:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ShoppingTemplate GetTemplate(int id)
        {
            var template = new PentaShoppingorder
            {
                OrderId = id.ToString(),
                Date = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                Title = "Template title",
                Price = 5000,
                Supplier = Supplier[1],

            };
            return template;
        }
```

When i look at the debugger the url seems fine, so i assume its its api, thats the problem i just can't find out whats wrong with it.

I have tried to add [FromRoute] aswell, but its the same result.

Comment: Can you show the `Attributes` on your controller?

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call `api/SampleData/${this.props.match.params.orderId}`

instead of `api/SampleData/GetTemplate/${this.props.match.params.orderId}`

With your current route convention is `[Route("api/[controller]")]`, you are excluding the action from the mix.

If you would like to get the action involved set your route attribute to `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`